# Combining Two tables and displaying data with count in sql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables as table1 and table2 and it contains Field1, Field2, Field3 in both tables. I need to combine and display the count of Field3 with distinct field2 value from both the tables.

ex:

```
Field1 Field2 Field3
1 | India  | VERIFIED
2 | US     | VERIFIED
3 | India  | VERIFIED
```

I need the output like count of Field2 with the Field2 Value where Field3 = verified

India (2) 
US (1)

I dont have any idea about join statement and i am beginner in SQL PHP.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where is your second table?

Comment: Two tables are under same Database. Both having same column names. I need Field values & Count from both tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Field2, count(Field2)
FROM (SELECT * FROM table1  UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2) AS t
WHERE t.Field3 = 'VERIFIED'
GROUP BY Field2
```

`UNION`combines two sql query results into one. You could also apply your filter during the two  queries.

But having two tables with exact the same field indicates bad databse design - You might read a bit about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for getting a clue of good relational database design.

UPDATE: regarding the fiddle by paqogomez I identified a small problem. I needed to add the keyword `ALL` to avoid SQl treating my results as Sets and remvoing double entries (if two entries from both tables are exact the same) by default the `DISTINCT` keyword is applied.

Comment: This indeed works perfectly.  Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2a7d/2)  (I was working up this exact solution, but you beat me to it.) +1

Comment: Your fidle showed me what I still missed - I updated my solution to `UNION ALL`

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I checked it in fiddle. It works awesome. But when i integrate into my local php page, it throws some error. I feel its my end only. Do i need to add any double or single quotes within the sql statement ?

Comment: What is the error first of all... secondly, mysql likes backticks around its field names, that would be my first guess.

Comment: I am executing this sql statement by assigning to a variable and parsing to mysqli_query().                                      $rs_city = mysqli_query($con,$sql);  I already have $con connection.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'FIELD2' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\pages\filtertabs.php on line 69

Comment: can you paste the complette line 69 for us? Is your query sorrounded by `'` single quotes?

Comment: $sql = SELECT CITY, count(CITY)
FROM (SELECT * FROM carstbl UNION SELECT * FROM bikestbl) AS t WHERE t.STATUS = 'VERIFIED' GROUP BY CITY;

$rs_city = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

Comment: The query needs to  be a String - so try writing this:
`"$sql = SELECT CITY, count(CITY) FROM (SELECT * FROM carstbl UNION SELECT * FROM bikestbl) AS t WHERE t.STATUS = 'VERIFIED' GROUP BY CITY;"` - I added double qutoes sorrounding the string.

Comment: If one of the given answers helped you to solve the question, please feel free to mark it as 'accepted answer' to help future visitors of this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(Field2) AS total,Field2
FROM (SELECT * FROM t1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM t2) AS t
WHERE t.Field3='VERIFIED'
GROUP BY t.Field2;
```

Comment: He want to count it from two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result by using only 1 table by trying somthing lke this:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 WHERE FIELD3 = 'VERIFIED' GROUP BY FIELD2;
```

This might be helpful to you.

Comment: He want to count it from two tables

Comment: but the desired result can be achieved by using only 1 table. thwn why should we use the another 1.

Comment: I already reading from single table. Now i want to read from two or multiple tables.

Comment: Then you have to share some sample data with us of second table. Without that nothing is possible.

Comment: When he says both tables are the same, I think its easy to say we're pretty close to possible.